# ImageList_Add returns -1 on PC controlled with pcAnywhere

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, windows-xp, delphi-7

One of our applications fails on computers that are controlled via pcAnywhere because the ImageList_Add() WinAPI function fails to add the image/mask after some time. The function returns -1 and the number of icons in the imagelist doesn't change. On all other computers this is no problem. What is interesting is that we can add 99 bitmaps (LoadBitmap) to the imagelist but by adding the 100th bitmap ImageList_Add stops working.

I tried to write a simple test application that fills the imagelist by a specified number of bitmaps but that didn't cause the problem. So I'm standing in the rain. Does anybody have seen this strange behavior or has a solution or explanation for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe pcAnywhere is doing something that generate a resource leak on the controlled system... And ImageList cannot add a new image because of this. Then maybe the sample application just not trigged the critical mass .

There was many years ago that I touched an pcAnywere installation.